# How can I add a postgres database connection to an ApolloServer Instance and deploy using serverless?

Tags: postgresql, graphql, serverless, typeorm, apollo-server

I would like to deploy graphql api using AWS. I successfully managed to deploy with no DB using serverless. However, I would know like to add a PostgresDB instance first locally and then deploy it.

I tried using the middy middleware but I'm unsure how to do it properly.

I'm using Typescript, TypeORM, Postgres, NodeJS, serverless, middy, apollo-server-lambda and gql.

**Below Server**

```
import { ApolloServer } from 'apollo-server-lambda';
import { resolvers } from './resolvers';
import { typeDefs } from '../src/type-defs';
import "reflect-metadata";
import middy from 'middy';
import { doNotWaitForEmptyEventLoop } from 'middy/middlewares';
import { database } from './database';

const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({ resolvers, typeDefs });
const graphqlHandler1 = apolloServer.createHandler();

export const graphqlHandler = middy(graphqlHandler1)
  .use(doNotWaitForEmptyEventLoop({ runOnError: true }))
  .use(database())
```

**Below Database connection**

```
import {createConnection} from "typeorm";
import {Photo} from "../models/photo";

export const database = () => ({
    before: async (_:any,next:any) => {
      await createConnection({
        type: "postgres",
        host: "localhost",
        port: 5432,
        username: "postgres",
        password: "password",
        database: "TSGQLTest",
        entities: [
            Photo
        ],
        synchronize: true,
        logging: false
    });
      next();
    },
  });
```

Comment: `middy` is now `@middy/core`. Check out the `middy-rds` middleware for some inspiration. https://github.com/willfarrell/middy-rds/blob/main/index.js

Answer (score 0):

Have middy manage your connections:

middy-postgres.ts

```
import * as pg from 'pg';
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
import * as bluebird from 'bluebird';

dotenv.config();
pg.defaults.ssl = true;
bluebird.promisifyAll(pg);
const databaseURI = process.env.DATABASE_URL || 'postgres://xxxax.com:5432';
const state = process.env.IS_OFFLINE ? 'Local Database Connection' : 'Remote Database Connection';

export default () => ({
    before: (handler, next) => {
        handler.event.client = new pg.Client(databaseURI);
        handler.event.client.connect()
            .then(() => console.log('connected', '=>', state))
            .then(next)
    },
    after:  (handler, next) => {
        handler.event.client.end()
            .then(() => console.log('closed', '=>', state))
            .catch(console.log)
            .then(next);
    },
    onError: (handler, next) => {
        handler.event.client.end()
            .then(() => console.log('closed', '=>', state))
            .then(next);
    },
});
```

..by passing the client through the event:

```
export const graphqlHandler = middy(graphqlHandler1)
  .use(doNotWaitForEmptyEventLoop({ runOnError: true }))
  .use(middyPostgres())
```